# get total amount of expenses per month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently working with 2 tables, expenses and income. To keep the structure simple and can see it, this is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/256cd64/2

The result I need from my query is the total amount for each month of the current year, for this and tried something like this:

```
select sum(e.amount) as expense, DATE_FORMAT(e.date,'%m') as month 
from expenses e
where year(e.date) = 2019
group by month
```

My problem with this is that it only takes me the months where there was registration and I would like it to take 12 months whether or not they have a registration, in the case that they did not return 0 as a total amount.

At the moment I am working with the table of expenses but I would like to have a single query that returns the monthly expenses and income, this is an example of the final output that I would like to obtain:

```
|   Month | Expense| Incomes |
|---------|--------|---------|
|       01|      0 |       0 |
|       02|   3000 |    4000 |
|       03|   1500 |    5430 |
|       04|  2430  |    2000 |
|       05|  2430  |    1000 |
|       06|  2430  |    1340 |
|       07|     0  |    5500 |
|       08|  2430  |    2000 |
|       09|  1230  |    2000 |
|       10|  8730  |    2000 |
|       11|  2430  |    2000 |
|       12|  6540  |    2000 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the month values and then use `left join` to match to expenses:

```
select coalesce(sum(e.amount), 0) as expense, m.month
from (select '01' as month union all
      select '02' as month union all
      select '03' as month union all
      select '04' as month union all
      select '05' as month union all
      select '06' as month union all
      select '07' as month union all
      select '08' as month union all
      select '09' as month union all
      select '10' as month union all
      select '11' as month union all
      select '12' as month
     ) m left join
     expenses e
     on year(e.date) = 2019 and
        DATE_FORMAT(e.date,'%m') = m.month
group by m.month;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/256cd64/4) is a db<>fiddle.

As for `income`, you should ask another question about that.

Comment: the query works as expected, however as I have many records, when doing a review; It takes too long because it runs through the entire table. I tried to create an index for the date column and try to change this part: `year(e.date) = 2019` but I still have the same problem, so I was wondering how I can optimize it? I don't know much about this topic, please could you guide me and tell me at least where to start

Comment: @FeRcHo . . . You should ask a *new* question about performance.  Your original query uses the `date()` function in the `where` clause, and that is going to preclude the use of an index.  It is not clear if an index would really help.  You need to provide more information, such as the size of the table, the keys, and so on.

Comment: thank you, you are right I will try to post a question about performance, with the query I currently have based on your answer here, I hope you can also help me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MONTH to get month value from your date column and then GROUP BY them to get your desired output as below-

```
SELECT SUM(e.amount) AS expense, 
MONTH(e.date) AS month    
FROM expenses e
WHERE YEAR(e.date) = 2019
GROUP BY MONTH(e.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `sum(e.amount) as expense` to: `COALESCE(sum(e.amount),0) as expense`

The `COALESCE` function returns the first non `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.month,
    COALESCE(t2.amount, 0) AS expenses,
    COALESCE(t3.amount, 0) AS incomes
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM expenses
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) t2
    ON t1.month = t2.month
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM incomes
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) t3
    ON t1.month = t3.month
ORDER BY
    t1.month;
```

Comment: This query will not search for the current year, I just want the expenses and income of 2019 for example

Comment: 'year(t2.date) = 2019 AND year(t3.date) = 2019' Pass in where condition hope your problem will resolve.